# How to do a text change located in quick launch

Tags: 2010

Will changing the name of a link under quick launch mess up my settings in which that link needs to gain access to a page?  The link goes where it needs to go...I just want to change the name under quick launch for people to know where to go to. Just want to make it a simplier name.  But I want the page it links to...to stay the same. I've very new to SharePoint as you can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Site Actions, SIte Settings and click on the Quick Launch link (or it will be the Navigation link if publishing is being utilized). There you will be able to edit the link text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Site Settings -> Navigation for changing links.

Once you open up that page scroll down to see Quick Launch.

Select the link and edit it.